# What is tmon and how can I use it?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I found a `tmon` utility in my CentOS 7.5 and I've googled that:

> TMON is conceived as a tool to help visualize, tune, and test the
>   complex thermal subsystem.
>
> ...
>
> For monitoring only:
>
> $ sudo ./tmon
>
> https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/tools/thermal/tmon

But as a result of the launch, I only get an error:

```
No thermal zones found, exit
```

on my E5-2620 v4 and kernel 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64.

I also found other poor mentions and similar topics (e.g. this one on RH: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1466991) but it's not cleared up how to use it for monitoring properly and what do this "zones" mean.

**UPD**
This CentOS is on baremetal server.

Comment: Maybe stating the obvious, but for starters that will only have a chance of working on bare-metal servers and probably won't work on a VPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to load certain kernel modules for your motherboard to get thermal zones readings, the following is a reading from an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS bare-metal server using lm-sensors package

```
root@vm02:~# sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +64.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +64.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +60.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +62.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +58.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

nct6776-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
Vcore:          +0.86 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:            +1.85 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
AVCC:           +3.34 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
+3.3V:          +3.33 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
in4:            +0.91 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in5:            +1.75 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in6:            +0.87 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
3VSB:           +3.49 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
Vbat:           +3.33 V  (min =  +2.70 V, max =  +3.63 V)
fan1:             0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:          1912 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:             0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:             0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan5:             0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
SYSTIN:         +37.0°C  (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermistor
CPUTIN:         +36.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN:         +32.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
PECI Agent 0:   +63.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)
                         (crit = +100.0°C)
PCH_CHIP_TEMP:   +0.0°C
PCH_CPU_TEMP:    +0.0°C
PCH_MCH_TEMP:    +0.0°C
intrusion0:    ALARM
intrusion1:    ALARM
beep_enable:   disabled
```

you can use the lm-sensors package to identify which modules you need to load, check `man sensors-detect`

Comment: lm_sensors is not required to use tmon. I use it on systems without sensors installed. If you don't see thermal zones, you probably need a newer kernel.

Comment: I did not state that one needs lm_sensors to use tmon, its just a good package that makes life easier.